# VBA RtlMoveMemory only works with ByVal

Tags: vba, memory

Working code is:

```
Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (pDest As Any, pSource As Any, ByVal ByteLen As Long)

Sub Test()

Dim Long1 As Long
Dim Long2 As Long

    Long1 = 1000
    CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(Long2), ByVal VarPtr(Long1), 4
    Debug.Print VarPtr(Long1)
    Debug.Print Long2
End Sub
```

I have two questions:

My understanding is that VB runtime released the memory of Long1 and Long2 when they go out of scope. Why does `Debug.Print VarPtr(Long1)` returns the same address in every run of the program? Does VB Runtime keeps a certain part of the memory for variables? I believe so, as even I did something (e.g. close a Chrome tab) to release memory from the heap it keeps show the same address.

Why do I need to use `ByVal` to get the correct result? I do understand that `CopyMemory` simply moves a number of bytes from the **address** pointed by the integer `VarPtr(Long1)` to the **address** pointed by the integer `VarPtr(Long2)`, but I don't know why I have to use the keyword `ByVal`, otherwise it simply returns `0`. I thought that maybe VBA takes `ByRef` as default, and with `ByRef` it means to copy the bytes from the address that store the address of `Long1` (basically the reference to the returned value of VarPtr which is simply an integer), which is nothing, to the address that store the address of `Long2`, which is also nothing. But VBA simply gives me error message if I deliberately use `ByRef`.

Comment: closing a Chrome tab won't impact the Excel memory management.  The OS does a good job of making every process think it has its own address space through process isolation.  I realise at the OS level Windows does page in and page out blocks but that won't be seen as such by Excel.exe

Comment: @SMeaden Thanks! I have no idea how OS works, thanks for the revelation. My naive interpretation was that VB Runtime keeps (or OS gives) a large chunk of memory when it starts up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primitive local variables are stored on the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)), so the address is depending from the order you call a routine, you can see this with an easy example:

```
Sub showAdresses()
    myTest
    callTest
    callTest
    myTest
End Sub

Sub callTest()
    myTest
End Sub

Sub myTest()
    Dim x As Long
    Debug.Print VarPtr(x)
End Sub
```

You will see the same address for the first and last call and another one for the calls in between - simply because there is space needed on the stack for the intermediate routine. When a subroutine finishes, the consumed space on the stack is released and (this is the nature of a stack) immediately reused, so if you call the same routine again, the same variable will get the same address (but VBA initializes it).

For the `ByVal` keyword when calling `CopyMemory`: I assume that the call to `VarPtr` returns a *pointer*, and you pass the *pointer* as value - else you would pass the *address* of the pointer.